# Is this a valid example of analytic continuation?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion, analytic-continuation

I am trying to understand (and then explain) analytic continuation as simply as possible.

**Question 1:** Is the following an example of analytic continuation?

---

The following function is defined for all $x$ except $x=1$. The following illustrates this function.

$$f(x)=1/(1-x)$$

---

The following series is a representation of $f(x)$ but only valid for $-1<x<1$. It is in fact the Taylor series for $f(x)$ developed around $x=0$.

$$ S_0(x) = 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots$$

---

The following series is another representation of $f(x)$ but this time valid for $1<x<5$. It is in fact the Taylor series for $f(x)$ developed around $x=3$.

$$S_3(x)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\left(x-3\right)-\frac{1}{8}\left(x-3\right)^2+\frac{1}{16}\left(x-3\right)^3-\frac{1}{32}\left(x-3\right)^4+\ldots$$

---

**Question 2:** Can we say that $S_3$ is an analytic continuation of $S_0$, where both represent $f(x)$ but in different domains?

**Question 3:** Does analytic continuation require an overlap of the domains? For the above example, this would require, for example, $S_3$ and $S_5$, the Taylor series developed around $x=3$ and $x=5$.

---

The following diagram visualises these functions.

[image]

Comment: $S_3$ is not an analytic continuation of $S_0$, since analytic continuation must agree with the extended function in the domain of definition.

Comment: @FreeZe so is $S_5$ an analytic continuation of $S_3$?

Comment: Two representations need to agree on an open set common to their domains.

Comment: @Aruralreader I'm not mathematically trained so can I interpret your comment as "the two representations must have domains that overlap"? I don't know why the intersection must be "open".

Comment: You can think of analytic continuation a little bit like expanding the domain of a function. This might be filling in a small hole (a removable singularity) or adding much larger regions. The easiest example would be something like $f(z)=z^2/z$ defined on $z\neq0$. Defining a second function $g(z)=z$ on all of $\Bbb C$, we have a function that agrees with $f(z)$ at every value of $z$ where $f$ is defined, but $g$ is defined on a larger set.

Comment: thanks @Clayton, so would $S_5$ be an analytic continuation of $S_3$ because the domains overlap?